# Calling WS with SSL in java

Tags: java, ssl, jks

I connect to a web service with this client that work fine:

```
WSCSI WSCS = new WSCSI("http://localhost:8080/ServiceV2/services/WSCSISoap?wsdl","WSCSI","WSCSISoap");
IScoring instance = new ScoringCFA(WSCS);

assertEquals(true, instance.statusService());
```

I need to use SSL, So i change the url to:
https://localhost:8181/ServiceV2/services/WSCSISoap?wsdl

And add this in the VM Options:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore="C:\cacerts.jks"
```

('Keytool -list -keystore "C:\cacerts.jks', when i run this command i see that the certificate that i need is there)

When i run the client get this error:

```
java.security.cert.CertificateException: No name matching localhost found.)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's probably because the cert you're using is issued against a specific hostname (www.myhost.com).  Try the solution in this [article](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/java-security-cert-certificateexception-no-name-matching-localhost-found/).
But be warned, the code sample is only intended for localhost testing, remove it once you move onto the integration/assembly testing on a proper server.

Comment: Thank you very much!
Now, when I have to deploy the proyect in production,

I would need that the cert have the name of the domain that I'm trying to connect?
(Thats a cert problem outside the code...?)
 
And 
If I deploy the client with this "FIX", the problem is that maybe I connect to a unknow host?

Comment: JMira - this 'fix' is not a fix, but a 'hack' only intended for localhost testing, you should remove that code before you go to production. Yes, the risk is you could be calling an improperly identified host (although the 'hack' will only work with 'localhost' as a host name).  In production, the URL you're trying to invoke has to match the hostname that the server is identifying with, so yes, the name in the cert needs to match the domain you're connecting to.  Hope this provides further clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me that [disabling SSL hostname verification](http://www.theserverside.com/discussions/thread.tss?thread_id=34538) might work for you. [Another example here](http://www.nakov.com/blog/2009/07/16/disable-certificate-validation-in-java-ssl-connections/).